# I made it up with no more than one. But one what?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> If you hope to reach more than six
>   You will need more than one of us
>   Wait, I think you can go from *un* to *dix*
>   That means French is weird, thus?
>   Though with just one, you can read these lines
>   For three months as well, this is fine
>   And you can sing from Do to Si
>   But how will you go to X from V?
>   Oh, that is right, you may need more than two
>   To find who we are. But will you?

Comment: I've never heard of Si being in the solfege... but according to Wikipedia it's a substitute for Ti, the 7th note, which is what I learned (USA, plus it's how they do it in The Sound Of Music, haha). Is Si more common where you are from?

Comment: @DanA. Yes, in here, it is "Do Ré Mi Fa Sol La Si" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note

Comment: Cool. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfège also has a cool history on the named scale. Learned my one new thing for the day, and it's only morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm gonna guess:

> Syllables

If you hope to reach more than six

> One to six are all one syllable words in English.. seven has two

Wait, I think you can go from un to dix
That means French is weird, thus?

> In French the numbers un (one) to dix (ten) are all one syllable.. except possibly quatre (four)

Though with just one, you can read these lines

> Eye, eyes and read are all one syllable, as are all the words in the question!

For three months as well, this is fine

> March, May and June are all one syllable

And you can sing from Do to Si

> All the note names are one syllable

But how will you go to X from V?

> W (double-u) is more than one syllable (three)

Oh, that is right, you may need more than two
To find who we are. But will you?

> Syllable itself is three syllables - *Credit @Mithrandir*. Initially thought the first line referred to the previous hint, but this makes more sense!

Title Bonus.. I made it up with no more than one. But one what?

> Each word in the title and the question is only one syllable! Impressive!

Comment: Syllables is 3 syllables, that might be what the last line is

Comment: @Mithrandir Cheers, read that that section wrong!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks for the edit! One day I'll get the formatting down :)

Comment: @Arth if you want a line break just put two spaces after each line :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I know.. it's just so unnatural that I forget!

Comment: Aye, aye! Edited a little bit because *quatre* can cause confusion sometimes.